# How can I avoid angering Beogh when I am confused?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-stone-soup

I had some orc allies that converted when they saw me due to my fervent worship of Beogh. Unfortunately, one of the less zealous orc wizards didn't convert, and confused me mid-combat. I was surrounded with allies, and whenever I tried to move the game asked me if it was really worth the risk.

What actions are safe to take near allies while confused to avoid accidentally attacking a friendly orc and incurring Beogh's wrath?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When confused near your allies, **DO NOT MOVE**. Attacking one of your allies will not only anger that ally, but can anger Beogh, causing all of your allies to turn on you. On the same note, you should not read-id scrolls near your followers, as Torment or Immolation will hit your followers and anger Beogh. I lost a very promising HoPr to an Immolation Scroll.

Safe moves are to simply use <kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>5</kbd> to wait until the confusion wears off, and let your followers deal with any enemies, or to drink a Potion of Curing, which will remove the `Confused` effect.

Comment: I've made the exact same mistake with a scroll of immolation and a very buff troop of orc warriors and knights.